# Form Validation in Ionic3

Tags: angular, ionic3

1. I had used angular form validation but It seems  that it only works
   on HTML component and not for the ionic component.
2. **I had tried "formControlName" but it could not work
   in `<ion-input>` & also not throw any error.**
3. **Here in the below code formControlName works fine with `<textarea>`**

   my .ts file:

   ```
    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) 
    {
     this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({ 
         'name': ['', Validators.required],
         'email': ['', Validators.required],
         'profile': ['', Validators.required]
     });

     this.userForm.get('name').disable();
     this.userForm.get('email').disable();
     this.userForm.get('profile').disable();
   }


   edit()
   {
     this.userForm.get('name').enable();
     this.userForm.get('email').enable();
     this.userForm.get('profile').enable();
   }
   ```

In My .html File:

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm" (submit)="saveUser()">
  <ion-label>Name</label>
  <ion-input formControlName="name" id="name"></ion-input>


  <ion-label>Email</label>
  <ion-input formControlName="email" id="email"></ion-input>

  <label for="profile">Profile Description</label>
  <textarea formControlName="profile" id="profile"></textarea>
  
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!userForm.valid">Submit</button>
</form>

<button round ion-button (click)="edit()">Edit</button>
```

Comment: Are you able to get changed data of Form? Put following code somewhere in html and see form value changes or not: {{userForm.value | json }}

Comment: is edit button not working? or is it submit button? what behavior do you see?

Comment: No All buttons are working Perfect the issue i am getting is - ion-input disable successfull but can't enable after edit button is called.                              while same methodology applied for the text-area field and is working for it.

Comment: try setting `type="button"` for the edit button in html

Comment: There is no problem in button.                                                                            ion-input in not enable while text-area is enable if button not work then why text-area is enabled.

Comment: Same issue : https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12904

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so much digging for this issue i had finally found the solution:
Also problem is from `<ion-input>` core the disabled property is sticked to it whether, we're trying to enable back **"enable"** wont work.
for that I am using this technique.

In .html file include:

```
<div id="tag">....stuff provided question .html file.....</div>
```

In .ts file I wrote:

```
edit()
{
   this.userForm.get('name').enable();
   this.userForm.get('email').enable();
   this.userForm.get('profile').enable();

   let field = document.getElementById("tag");
   let children = field.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++)
     {
      children[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
     }
```

}